# Deploy error in porto 2.1.0 Magento 2, _popus.less

Tags: magento-2.1

When I run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy those are the errors that will occur. by the way I just upgraded my magento version 2.0.7 to magento 2.1.1 and it gives error.

[image]

Comment: Go to the file and remove the ._lib-popup-button-close-icon class and deploy again.

Comment: Sorry but the problem still persists. It occurs again even if, I followed your instructions

Comment: We are facing same issue, please go to original theme file and remove. var files processed from original theme file.

Comment: Yes and it really bothers me. I've been searching from google for around 2 days and still no luck

Comment: What do you mean by removing the var files processed from original theme file?

Comment: You can find the porto theme files at /app/design/frontend/Porto something like that and search fr that file.

Comment: I just did that, I located the file _popups.less that's the one causing the problem. if I remove that one it will give mo more problem to the site

Comment: Yes, the problem is with that class while less compilation the class is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are facing same issue, please go to original theme file and remove `._lib-popup-button-close-icon` class and run setup:upgrade, deploy the static content again.

Remove below code from `app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/web/css/source/_popups.less`

```
._lib-popup-button-close-icon(
@popup-button-close__icon,
@popup-icon-font__content,
@popup-icon-font,
@popup-icon-font__size,
@popup-icon-font__line-height,
@popup-icon-font__color,
@popup-icon-font__color-hover,
@popup-icon-font__color-active,
@popup-icon-font__margin,
@popup-icon-font__vertical-align,
@popup-icon-font__position,
@popup-icon-font__text-hide
);
```

This issues [might cause for the reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24240134/less-inheritance-fails-with-undefined-class).

If you fells any styles issue, you have to write styles for that.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello I just did that I removed that class you instructed me but still the same the error is still there.